# Is there a kernel-mode callback for LdrLoadDll?

Tags: windows, callback, driver, hook, kernel-mode

I'm trying to make an exe profiler and now want to trace/log all Dlls that load/use in an exe by hooking `LdrLoadDll` in **kernel-mode driver** (I created the user-mode in the past).
My problem is in 64bit version of windows, because in 64bit I can't use **SSDT** hooking and I can't find any alternative solution for this.

In 64Bit there are kernel-mode callbacks like: **[PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff559951(v=vs.85).aspx)** (Alternative to hooking *CreateProcess*) but I can't find any solution for this case. Now my question is: Is there a kernel-mode callback for LdrLoadDll? Or do I have to find a solution for 64bit kernel hooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register a driver-supplied callback. Your callback will be called when a driver image or user image (DLL, EXE) is mapped into virtual memory.

Windows calls this callback at PASSIVE_LEVEL.